# How to trim Woocommerce short description (find text and trim everything after) via MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replace, woocommerce, find, trim

I have a e-commerce site running on Woocommerce with a long and short description with both same content. In my previous theme the short description was never visible so not a problem. Now I want to switch theme but during the test I noticed the issue of the same content on two places on the same page as the new theme uses short description properly. Rather than fixing the front-end I want to correct my data set for many products.

My question:

What would be a proper SQL select statement (to test) and the update statement (to execute) to go over the woocommerce products table - column short description and look for "More details" and simply delete everything after ... if "More details" exists.

Your support is very much appreciated! Thanks a ton in advance.

Erwin

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'text to replace', 'new text')
```

I tried that on both [DashikiDresses.com](http://www.dashikidresses.com) and [RatchetQueens.com](http://www.ratchetqueens.com) and it works